# How to select latest row by a user_id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
content: id, user_id, markdown
```

How do I select the latest id created by a certain user?

```
SELECT * FROM content
WHERE user_id = 2
```

So if rows 12,13 and 14 have user_id as 2, I want to select row 14

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM content
WHERE user_id = 2
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Also, if you have a table of users and you want to get the latest record for each:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM content c
    INNER JOIN (SELECT user_id, max(id) as maxid 
                FROM content 
                GROUP BY user_id) as c1 on c.id = c1.maxid
```

Comment: Since this is tagged mysql, `TOP` won't work.  `LIMIT` is the MySQL keyword.

Comment: and add "LIMIT 1" to return only one result

Comment: Fixed, sorry in sql-server world lately.

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL I think you'd need:

```
SELECT *
FROM content
WHERE user_id = 2
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

You could do a subselect and select the MAX timestamp (which may be safer) - but it doesn't look like you have a timestamp.

Comment: Whether the `max(timestamp)` is safer depends. If that timestamp updates on `update` then it's no longer a **creation** timestamp, but it really depends on what you want. Anyway there no real need for a subselect, you can just do a `order by timestamp desc limit 1`